# Best way to store and push contact info on Cordova apps

Tags: cordova, storage

I am writing a Cordova-based app, which serves as my organisation's internal phonebook app. It contains the data of individuals, such as phone number and e-mail

The employee database itself is on Microsoft SQL Server. I planned that the database will be partially duplicated on the client side, making app usable while offline.

So, here are my questions and concerns:

- In which format should I store my data? JSON seems to be not that good when it's time for searching.
- How could I store my data? If it's JSON, flieReader/Writer seems to be okay, but if it's not JSON then it's going to be harder.
- What is the best way to duplicate the database? Have to admit I have really no idea here.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Storage in Cordova has been known to come with a couple of quirks. You need to first identify which device platform you will be supporting so you can pick the best choice [HTML5 Storage option](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html).

One good alternative which I've seen people use is [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/). It makes database syncs much easier to manage. I know you're using MS SQL Server, but you still might want to take a look. Also look to see if Microsoft has something similar.